# Selenium-WebDriver UnhandeledPromiseRejectionWarning Error

Tags: node.js, selenium, selenium-webdriver

This is my first time using Selenium web driver. I am having issues 'getting' a web address. Here is my code:

```
const {Builder, By, Key, until} = require('selenium-webdriver'),
  app = require('express'),
  express = app();

let driver = new Builder().forBrowser('chrome').build();

driver.get('https://google.com'); //<---- known bug(doesn't open proper page)
```

So there, I am just trying to open google.com Please tell me what I'm doing wrong. Anyway, here's the error when I do, node app.js:

```
    DevTools listening on ws://127.0.0.1:12825/devtools/browser/cd5a8eae-4ff0-482e-9f80-cf49f4c3f794
(node:11584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: WebDriverError: unknown error: Runtime.executionContextCreated has invalid 'context': {"auxData":{"frameId":"A07868DB3EACD45E5235CB0DA6162B30","isDefault":true,"type":"default"},"id":1,"name":"","origin":"://"}
  (Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
  (Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
    at Object.checkLegacyResponse (C:\Users\Ben Levy\Desktop\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\error.js:585:15)
    at parseHttpResponse (C:\Users\Ben Levy\Desktop\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:533:13)
    at Executor.execute (C:\Users\Ben Levy\Desktop\bot\node_modules\selenium-webdriver\lib\http.js:468:26)
    at process._tickCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:68:7)
(node:11584) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Unhandled promise rejection. This error originated either by throwing inside of an async function without a catch block, or by rejecting a promise which was not handled with .catch(). (rejection id: 1)
(node:11584) [DEP0018] DeprecationWarning: Unhandled promise rejections are deprecated. In the future, promise rejections that are not handled will terminate the Node.js process with a non-zero exit code.
```

**Thanks!**

Comment: From the stack trace we can see that there's an [error reading/parsing](https://github.com/SeleniumHQ/selenium/blob/bc10b674bf0f0b0dadfde9435584813224d02618/javascript/node/selenium-webdriver/lib/http.js#L533) the answer from the Webdriver server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From the error

```
(Session info: chrome=70.0.3538.110)
(Driver info: chromedriver=2.9.248315,platform=Windows NT 6.3 x86_64)
```

I can see it running old `chromedriver 2.9` and not compatible with  the Chrome, download the latest version from [here](http://chromedriver.chromium.org/downloads).

Comment: @user9985211, please provide your own answer if you've found a solution. Accept your answer.